# Time taken to go downstream when the time differences are only given

Tags: contest-math, ratio

> A crew can now row a certain course up the stream in $84$ minutes;
> they can row the same course down stream in $9$ minutes less than they
> can row it in still water. How long would they take to row down with
> the stream?

My solution approach :- 
Let the speed of the boat be $x$ units.
Let the speed of the stream be $y$ units.
Let the distance be $d$ units.

Upstream time = $\frac{d}{x-y} = 84$ minutes
Downstream time = $\frac{d}{x+y}$
Still water time = $\frac{d}{x}$

As per the question :-
$\frac{d}{x}$ - $\frac{d}{x+y}$ = $9$

Now I am getting stuck after this as this now has $3$ variables and only $2$ equations and how can we find the value of all the variables. I do not see any way ahead. Is the question incomplete? Please help me with this!!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The question isn't incomplete per se, rather you will not be able to solve for all the variables. The good thing, is that you do not need to solve for all the variables, only the expression $\frac{d}{x+y}$.

Comment: Thanks..I was able to solve this...

Comment: What did you get as your answer? I'm getting that there are multiple (not infinite) answers...

Comment: yes...there will be two answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how all the terms have $d$ in the numerator. This motivates us to treat $d$ as a constant and solve for $x,y$ in terms of $d$. Dividing by $d$ on both sides, we have
$$\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x-y}=\frac{84}{d}\\ \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+y}=\frac{9}{d}\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x-y}=\frac{84}{d}\\ \frac{y}{x(x+y)}=\frac{9}{d}\end{cases}$$
Since we only want to find $\frac{d}{x+y}$. Make the substitution $u=x+y$, and then put everything in terms of $u$ and $y$.
$$\begin{cases} \frac{1}{u-2y}=\frac{84}{d}\\ \frac{y}{u(u-y)}=\frac{9}{d}\end{cases}$$
Dividing the two equations gives
$$\frac{u(u-y)}{y(u-2y)}=\frac{28}{3}$$
$$3u^2-3uy=28uy-56y^2$$
$$3u^2-31uy+56y^2=0$$
$$(3u-7y)(u-8y)=0$$
$$u=\frac{7}{3}y,8y$$
Since the speed of the boat should be faster than the stream (so that they can travel upstream), we have
$$x>y$$
$$x+y>2y$$
$$u>2y$$
Hence, both of these answers are possible

**Case 1: $u=\frac{7}{3}y$**
Substituting back into our first equation, we have
$$\frac{1}{u-2y}=\frac{84}{d}$$
$$d=84(u-2y)$$
$$d=84(\frac{1}{3}y)$$
$$d=28y$$
Hence,
$$\frac{d}{u}=\frac{28y}{\frac{7}{3}y}=\boxed{12}$$

**Case 2: $u=8y$**
Substituting back into our first equation, we have
$$\frac{1}{u-2y}=\frac{84}{d}$$
$$d=84(u-2y)$$
$$d=84(6y)$$
$$d=504y$$
Hence,
$$\frac{d}{u}=\frac{504y}{8y}=\boxed{63}$$

I guess both of these answers are acceptable then, as I can't find any reason to conclude either as extraneous.

Comment: yes...even I am getting the same two result...but still I can't imagine how it will be possible in real life? why two times? anyway that's a separate question..

Comment: Does the question have a source? What does it say about the answer?

Comment: It gives both the answer and it's a question from a competitive exam book. In the book's hint, it solved using putting in the option but I wanted to know how can we solve this mathematically.

Comment: Ok, if it was a multiple choice then that explains how both answers could exist.

Comment: @amWhy is the link you provided the correct one? I'm not sure what you are pointing out?

Comment: Likely not.  My laptop is sluggish when I copy a link, if it copies, so when I paste, it is sometimes something I hadn't just copied.  I'll deleted the comment.  But on meta, if interested, you can search for "Enforcement of Quality Standards" in the search bar, and select the post with over 80 votes.

Comment: I went back and searched, @Alan:  [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).  Just something to read, review, and keep in mind.  Cheers!